# Header is added when exporting column of type image with BCP to files

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I export a column of type `image` to files using this command:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
'BCP "SELECT file_name FROM file_table WHERE id = 11 " 
queryout "C:\bcpdir\test.xml" -T -N'
```

In SQL Management Studio, I can see the hex value of the field starts with `0x3C3F786D6C` which is correct for an XML file (`<?xml`).

However, the command above seem to add an 4 byte header to the file. How can I use BCP without this header?

Comment: This describe the same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cdf06766-ce97-4d8f-9a96-aa9b2d011e67/extra-bytes-output-when-using-sql-server-2008-bcp-utility-to-export-files-in-a-database-table-to-a?forum=transactsql

Comment: By not using `-N` and by executing the BCP command from commandline, I get the option to set prefix to `0` instead of `8`. But I would like to be able to do it from the `EXEC` command.

Answer (score 2):

The solution seem to be to first execute BCP manually, set prefix to 0 in the user dialog. And then use the generated `.fmt`-file as in this command:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE my_id = 11 " 
queryout "C:\bcpdir\bcpout.xml" -T -f "C:\bcpdir\bcp.fmt'
```